# twilio API keeps sending request until socket hangs up error occurs

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I have been trying to solve this error from a long time. I could not find a similar problem online. I am sending a request through postman to twilio API for whatsapp. Everything seems ok. The promise should send a JSOM object in response but it keeps sending request until socket hangs up error occurs. Here is my code

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const { response } = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

exports.sendMessages = function(sender, reciever, message) {
  const accountSid = process.env.ACCOUNT_S_ID;
  const authToken = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN;
  const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 
  client.messages
  .create({
    from: 'whatsapp:+'+sender,
    body: message,
    to: 'whatsapp:+'+reciever
  })

  .then(response => {
    return {
      data: JSON.stringify(response),
  }})
  .catch(e => { console.error('Got an error:', e.code, e.message); });
}
```

Calling the API

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
// for parsing application/json
const send = require('./index');
let endPoint = process.env.ENDPOINT;
app.post(endPoint, function (req, res) {
send.sendMessages('14155238886', '393200149462','test message');
});
const port = process.env.PORT; 
app.listen(port);
console.log('Successfully connected to ' +port);
```

Comment: Hello. In order to give some proper feedback on this, can you show where and how do you call this "sendMessages" function?

Comment: @ŽilvinasJocius 
I have added the code kindly have a look